# Charging nicd battery with pwm

Tags: charger, nicd-battery

Hi I plan to build charger circuit to charge high capacity nicd battery. The charger will output 40A , is it safe to limit and reduce the current using pwm  IGBT/mosfet so the output will be pulse ?

[image]!

Comment: Yes, if you put it an appropriate circuit. What circuit do you intend to use?

Comment: This is the base circuit...using 74HC14 to control the pwm